# Citing two authors with alphadin results in wrong output

Tags: bibliographies, bibliographystyle

When citing a URL with two authors, they don't get displayed properly,

The biliography listed below results in all of the author's name being capitalized, while I need to have it like seen in the example below, *SURNAME, Firstname*

[image]

```tex
\usepackage{babel}[ngerman]
\addto\captionsgerman{\renewcommand{\refname}{Reference}}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

...

\bibliographystyle{alphadin}
\bibliography{document}

\end{document}
```

```tex
@misc{mac-tutor,
    author = "{John Josheph O'Connor, Edmund Frederick Robertson}",
    title = "{Abu'l Abbas al-Fadl ibn Hatim Al-Nayrizi}",
    year = "1999",
    howpublished = "\url{https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Al-Nayrizi/}",
    note = "[Online; Abruf am 12. Dezember 2020]"
 }
```

what wold be the correct way to approach this?

Comment: Off-topic: `\usepackage{babel}[ngerman]` isn't correct. It should be `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`.

Comment: Please show the bib entry for the Nelsen piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma `,` in the list of name for authors is not to separate different authors but for last name, first name separator. Multiple authors are separated by the `and` keyword. The format of names is

```
Author = {last name, first name and last name, first name and ...}
```

the other problem with the original post is the use of both `"` and `{`, `}` to encode the author field. So the `author` field should be

```
author = "O'Connor, John Josheph  and Robertson, Edmund Frederick",
```

or

author = {O'Connor, John Josheph  and Robertson, Edmund Frederick},

Comment: Hi, it results in both names still being capitalized [imgur](https://imgur.com/a/U3TjPnO)

Comment: What do you get with a single author?

Comment: please refer to the question, i've included a screenshot of [Nel00]

Comment: do not use both `"` and `{` to wrap the author field.

Comment: Yes, thank you!